# SSAS error when deploying cube in BIDs

Tags: string, hash, ssas, bids

I am getting the following error when deploying. This is in a cube which was working fine, all that has changed is a key column in one of the dimensions.

Internal error: Failed to generate a hash string

I have no idea what is causing this but even if I change the dimension back to how it was and try to deploy I get the same error.

If anyone has seen this or knows how to fix it please respond.

Answer (score 0):

By changing a key column I assume you renamed it and if so you will need to update your schema diagram in BIDS and re-process before deployment.